# Converting uint8_t[4] to unsigned long

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to convert an `uint8_t[4]` (or just 4 uint8_t's) into a single unsigned long (Specifically the Data1 part of the `GUID` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/14288352-43c3-4e4d-a3f1-e924a8261d2b) struct from `Rpc.h`

My, admittedly naive, approach was the following:

```
UUID newUUID;
newUUID.Data1 = 0x0a << 24;
newUUID.Data1 = 0x04 << 16;
...
```

But, as I could have told myself, the last line overwrites the middle one, causing the newUUID.Data1 to be `00040000` instead of `0a040000`

How do I go about setting the 9th-16th most significant bit, while preserving the 1st-8th most significant bit?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `|=` operator to set these new, non-overlapping ranges of bits:

```
UUID newUUID;
newUUID.Data1 = 0x0a << 24;
newUUID.Data1 |= 0x04 << 16;
```

Comment: This will cause undefined behaviour for some inputs (I think from OP's question they want to translate any possible values that might be in the GUID, not just `0x0a`) . The operand should be converted to 32-bit unsigned before shifting

Comment: @M.M `int` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits on both Windows and Posix

Comment: @Ivan `int` is signed. Also I have programmed on Windows computers with 16-bit int so I doubt that claim.

Comment: @M.M Shifting in sign bit has implementation-defined behavior, not undefined. For Windows I obviously meant Win32. 16-bit Windows are not relevant today.

Comment: @Ivan shifting into the sign bit has undefined behaviour (C17 6.5.7/4). Also, you can build and run 16-bit programs even in modern Windows.  (It works out-of-the-box in 32-bit Windows 10; for 64-bit Windows 10 you have to install NTVDM to run the executable)

Comment: @M.M This has been actually changed in C17 - [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1817.html). I think you are looking at outdated draft of C17. This is a backport of C++ [DR1457](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1457) which was included in C++14. I general I would recommend always comparing C behavior with C++ since C standard are largely outdated a receive their changes only after few years. Plus even if C standard does not receive some changes, compilers usually use C++ semantics over C.

Comment: @Ivan N2176 does not have that change, my understanding is that N2176 is the same as C17

Answer (score 3):

This is such a common thing in work that I do that I've defined a few macroes for it:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define B4TODW_LE(c0, c1, c2, c3) (uint32_t) ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c0) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c1) << 8) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c2) << 16) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c3) << 24))
#define B4TODW_BE(c0, c1, c2, c3) (uint32_t) ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c3) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c2) << 8) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c1) << 16) | ((uint32_t) (uint8_t) (c0) << 24))
```

You could just do then:

```
newUUID.Data1 = B4TODW_BE(0x0a, 0x04, ...);
```

Comment: Why macro and not a function?

Comment: @Ivan It could just as easily be a function too.

Comment: What is the reason for the double casting (The (uint32_t) and (uint8_t))?